# How to join one-to-one basic element to entity?

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa

I have 2 tables `user` and `user_password` and I want to load `User`entity so that `password` field in entity gets populated when entry in `user_password` table exist.

Tables:

```
user
--------
id
name

user_password
--------
user_id
password
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    @Column( name = "name" )
    private String name;

    // @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable( name = "user_password", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "user_id" ) )
    @Column( name = "password" )
    private String password;

}
```

It works when I use `@ElementCollection` and change the `password` field from String to List but the `user_id` column in `user_password` is also a primary key which means there will never be more than 1 password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name="user_password",
                pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="user_id"))
public class User implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Column(table = "user_password", name = "password" )
    private String password;
    ...
}
```